# How to use implode function

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array ( [e] => 
        [r] => 
        [c] => 
        [Overflow] => 
        [f] =>     
        [b] => [
        true] => 
        [Stck] => 
        [d] => 
        [js] => 
    )
```

and i need to get this

```
e, r, c, Overflow, f, b, true, stck, d, js
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

The data you want is in the keys of your array, not the values. So you have to implode the keys:

```
implode(', ', array_keys($array));
```

Comment: Answering bad questions just encourages more bad questions

Answer (score 1):

use `implode()` implode — Join array elements with a string
[Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)